# ajax progress loading does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am now in javascript, I am trying to display a indictor icon when ajax  starts and hide it when it finishes, below is my code:

```
CSS:
 div.ajax-progress {
      //some setting and url
}
<body>
   <div class="ajax-progress"></div>
</body>
Javascript:

$('#fileToUpload').on('change', function(e) {

            var file = e.target.files[0];
            var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
            imageId = cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.fileManager.add(file);


            $.ajax({
            url: 'loadfile.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout : 60000,
            beforeSend :function(){
                $(".ajax-progress").show();
            }，
            success: function (html) {}
           $(".ajax-progress").hide();
             //doing something}
        });
    });
```

but nothing happens, any idea? appreciated.

Comment: $(".ajax-progress").hide(); write into success function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put  `$(".ajax-progress").show();` before the call of ajax `$.ajax({});` and them hide it in the succes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's the same to what you have in your code but you commented out the success closing bracket }

you can also use console.log() or alert() to see what's going on in your code.

Comment: that is typing mistake, console in beforSend actually runs, but it does not show up, thank you for response

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your ajax as below:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'loadfile.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   async: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   timeout : 60000,
   beforeSend :function(){
      //do something
   }，
   success: function (html) {
      //doing something
   }
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(".ajax-progress").show();
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(".ajax-progress").hide();
});
```

This will show and hide `$(".ajax-progress")` in all your ajax requests within the application.